# livereload (browser-sync) work just once

Tags: node.js, web, sass, gulp, browser-sync

The problem is that when i'm start

> gulp watch

and change sass file, the page is reloading and build the project just once. Then it stop on task sass and if i want change other sass files - nothing happend then(see logs below). How could i solve it?

```
gulp.task('sass', wrapPipe(function(success, error) {
     return gulp.src('app/css/scss/style.scss')
         .pipe(sass({
             includePaths: [
                 './bower_components/foundation-sites/scss'
             ]
         }).on('error', error))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
         .pipe(browserSync.reload({
             stream: true
         }));

    }));

    gulp.task('livereload', function () {
        browserSync.init({
            server: "./app",
            notify: false
        });
    });

    gulp.task('watch', ['livereload'], function(){
        gulp.watch('app/css/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    });
```

This is logs:

```
[18:52:39] Starting 'livereload'...
[18:52:39] Finished 'livereload' after 20 ms
[18:52:39] Starting 'watch'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[18:52:39] Finished 'watch' after 33 ms
[BS] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.0.95:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.0.95:3001
 -------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./app
[18:52:50] Starting 'sass'...
[BS] 1 file changed (style.css)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what behavior who want other than detecting subsequent modified .scss files.  For that, what happens if you add a return:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['livereload'], function(){
    return gulp.watch('app/css/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```